# How to build Java application that employs Processing 1.5 with NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, processing

I have developed a project that consists in a GUI to draw information in a drawing area made with Processing 1.5.

I decided to use Processing 1.5 because of the problems that arise with OpenGL implementation in Processing 2.x.

I have followed the instrutions that appear in the next sites to add Processing 1.5 core.jar library (I use only the basic drawing primitives and P3D) to my project:

http://www.sebastianoliva.com/2010/03/usar-processing-en-java/trackback/
http://www.eliotlash.com/2011/08/processing-for-programmers/
http://www.creativeapplications.net/processing/craft-your-processing-sketches-in-eclipse/
http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/3411/coding-against-multiple-versions-of-processing-in-netbeans/p1

Up to the moment, the project is almost finished, and runs perfectly on NetBeans, but when I build the jar file to distribute it, the Processing screen doesn't appear on the GUI.

Can someone please help me to figure out what to add to the javac or to the VM parameters on Net Beans Project Configuration to make the program work?

Comment: What happens when you run the exported jar via the command prompt?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thank you very much for your interest in my question! I tried to run the file from the command prompt and the result is the same: the jInternalFrame in which I set up a jPanel to put the Processing canvas appears blank :-( Also I followed up the suggestions in the following page to add Processing library and keep up having the same problem: http://www.oslunaticos.com.br/2012/02/processing-no-netbeans/

Comment: @KevinWorkman Could you please suggest me where should I put the required folder with the vlw font?